# Printing array of hashes reults in a single column instead of a row in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, file, csv, hash

I want to print and array of hashes in a single column but my output is printing in a row

```
products = {"name":"kumar","results":[{"class":"one","site":[{"english":"twenty"}, {"english":"fouty"},{"english":"three"}]}]}

CSV.open("product.csv", 'wb') do |f|
productHash = products
  if productHash.haskey("results")
    productHash["results"].each do |p|
      if p.haskey("site")
        p["site"].each do |s|
          f << s["english"]
        end
      else
         f << "English not found"
     end
   else
     f << "results not found"
 end
```

The above program prints results in below style

```
 twenty
 foutrty
 three
```

I want this to be printed as

```
 twenty   fourty   three
```

also i need a new line at end of every results hash because i have more than one hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `f.prints` instead of `<<`.

The following outputs `twenty fouty three` and if there were more than one hash each would be on a different line because of the `f.print "\n"`.

```
products = {"name"=>"kumar","results"=>[{"class"=>"one","site"=>[{"english"=>"twenty"}, {"english"=>"fouty"},
        {"english"=>"three"}]}]}

File.open("product.csv", 'wb') do |f|
    productHash = products
    if productHash.has_key?("results")
        productHash["results"].each do |p|
            if p.has_key?("site")
                p["site"].each do |s|
                    f.print "#{s["english"]} "
                end
                f.print "\n"
            else
                f.print "English not found\n"
            end
        end

    else
            f.print "results not found\n"
    end
end
```

Edit:
Haha I almost went back to add the bit about printing a tab. Change `f.print "#{s["english"]} "` to `f.print "#{s["english"]}\t"`. It will leave an extra space or tab at the end of the line but in order to make as few changes as possible I figured it was ok.

Comment: Still it is not priniting in a tab